# How to pass down only the contents of a javascript object, but without iterating through each value?

Tags: javascript, json

**Description**

I have this:

```
db.get('mydata')
      .push({ id, obj})
      .write()
```

which pushes something to a database / json file. So I want to put the `id` into my database, and also the object; Internally, the object looks like this:

```
{
    name: "John",
    age:  42,
    job: "carpenter"
}
```

... and the id is just a number.

**The Problem**

When I do the push as quoted above, my db will look like this:

```
{
id: 12312312312
obj: {
        name: "John",
        age:  42,
        job: "carpenter"
     }
}
```

However: I don't want the `obj:` thing in there. So: How can I only pass the *contents* of my javascript object, so that the results looks like:

```
{
    id: 12312312312
    name: "John",
    age:  42,
    job: "carpenter"
}
```

**PS:** I know that I could go through every property in my object and do something like

```
db.get('mydata')
      .push({ id, obj.name, obj.age, obj.job})
      .write()
```

...but there must surely be a better solution available?

**PS2:** 
I also know I could do something like this:

```
    obj.id = id;
    db.get('mydata')
      .push(obj)
      .write()
```

but I am not sure if this is very elegant.

Comment: I think you should be able to `.push({ [id]: obj })`

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just append the id property to the obj before you add it?

```
obj.id = id;
db.get('mydata')
      .push(obj)
      .write()
```

Answer (score 2):

One option you can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
const newObject = Object.assign({}, obj, {id});
db.get('mydata')
      .push(newObject)
      .write()
```

Another option is to use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```
db.get('mydata')
      .push({...obj, id})
      .write()
```

Comment: or es6 version: `const newObject = {id, ...obj};`